# Two columns are added instead of 4 in third table hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Hi I have **Many to One** relationship which is **Unidirectional** in Lawyer table and I have used **@jointable** annotation to create third table, so when I insert lawyer corresponding country state city and district id should be inserted in third table.

But the problem is only `state_code and lawyer_batch_no` is inserting and rest of the column is not getting inserted in third table.

Although I have setted every dependent dependency in lawyer object.

this is the query is fired

```
Hibernate: select state_.state_code, state_.abbreviation as abbrevia2_18_, state_.COUNTRY as COUNTRY4_18_, state_.NAME as NAME3_18_ from state state_ where state_.state_code=?
02:12:42,527 TRACE BasicBinder:81 - binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [UP]
02:12:42,576 TRACE BasicExtractor:78 - extracted value ([abbrevia2_18_] : [VARCHAR]) - [UP]
02:12:42,576 TRACE BasicExtractor:78 - extracted value ([COUNTRY4_18_] : [VARCHAR]) - [IND]
02:12:42,577 TRACE BasicExtractor:78 - extracted value ([NAME3_18_] : [VARCHAR]) - [Uttar Pradesh]
Hibernate: insert into lawyer (court_of_practise, date_of_birth, experience_summary_id, first_name, last_name, user_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
02:12:42,588 TRACE BasicBinder:69 - binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [null]
02:12:42,588 TRACE BasicBinder:81 - binding parameter [2] as [TIMESTAMP] - [Wed Dec 14 02:12:42 IST 2016]
02:12:42,589 TRACE BasicBinder:81 - binding parameter [3] as [INTEGER] - [4]
02:12:42,589 TRACE BasicBinder:81 - binding parameter [4] as [VARCHAR] - [sofi]
02:12:42,590 TRACE BasicBinder:81 - binding parameter [5] as [VARCHAR] - [gupta]
02:12:42,590 TRACE BasicBinder:81 - binding parameter [6] as [BIGINT] - [4]
Hibernate: insert into lawyer_lscd (state_code, lawyer_batch_no) values (?, ?)
02:12:42,596 TRACE BasicBinder:81 - binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [UP]
02:12:42,596 TRACE BasicBinder:81 - binding parameter [2] as [INTEGER] - [4]
```

This is the lawyer pozo

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "lawyer")
class Lawyer{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "lawyer_batch_no")
    private int lawyerbatchNo;

@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Country.class, optional = true)
    @JoinTable(name = "lawyer_lscd", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "lawyer_batch_no",unique=true), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "country_code"))
    private Country country;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = State.class, optional = true)
    @JoinTable(name = "lawyer_lscd", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "lawyer_batch_no",unique=true), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "state_code"))
    private State state;
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = City.class, optional = true)
    @JoinTable(name = "lawyer_lscd", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "lawyer_batch_no",unique=true), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "city_code"))
    private City city;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = District.class, optional = true)
    @JoinTable(name = "lawyer_lscd", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "lawyer_batch_no",unique=true), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "district_code"))
    private District district;

...........................................
getter setter

}
```

This is the main method where I have tried setting the country state city and district into the lawyer object

```
    Lawyer lawyer = new Lawyer();
    lawyer.setFirstName("sofi");
    lawyer.setLastName("gupta");
    lawyer.setDateOfBirth(new Date());

    Country country = new Country();
    country.setCountry_code("IND");
    country.setAbbreviation("IND");
    country.setName("India");

    State state = new State();
    state.setState_code("UP");
    state.setAbbreviation("UP");
    state.setName("Uttar Pradesh");
    state.setCountry(country);

    City city = new City();
    city.setCity_code("BNDA");
    city.setCityName("Banda");
    city.setState(state);

    City city2 = new City();
    city2.setCity_code("LKO");
    city2.setCityName("Lucknow");
    city2.setState(state);

    District district = new District();
    district.setDistrict_code("MUA");
    district.setName("MAHUA");
    district.setCity(city);

    District district1 = new District();
    district1.setDistrict_code("MAHOBA");
    district1.setName("MAHOBA");
    district1.setCity(city);

    city.getDistricts().add(district);
    city.getDistricts().add(district1);


    state.getCity().add(city);
    state.getCity().add(city2);

    country.getState().add(state);

    lawyer.setCountry(country);
    lawyer.setState(state);
    lawyer.setCity(city);
    lawyer.setDistrict(district);


    LawyerDao clawDao = (LawyerDaoImpl) applicationContext.getBean("lawyerDaoImpl");
    clawDao.saveLayer(lawyer);
```

This is my save method in dao class

```
public Lawyer saveLayer(Lawyer lawyer) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    org.hibernate.Transaction tran = session.beginTransaction();
    int lawyerId = 0;
    if (session.isOpen()) {
        lawyerId = (Integer) session.save(lawyer);
        tran.commit();
        session.flush();
    }
    Lawyer savedLawyer = (Lawyer) session.get(Lawyer.class, lawyerId);
    session.close();
    return savedLawyer;
}
```

Comment: Using the same join table for 4 different associations doesn't make sense. Each association should have its own join table.

Comment: @JBNizet  Thanks for the response, You mean to say that i should create lawyer_country,lawyer_state,lawyer_city and lawyer_district four different table

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.